# Read / Write Haskell Integer in two's complement representation

Tags: haskell, binary, integer, twos-complement

I need to read and write Integers in a way that is compatible with what Java does with it's [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray()) class:

> Returns a byte array containing the two's-complement representation of
>   this BigInteger. The byte array will be in big-endian byte-order: the
>   most significant byte is in the zeroth element. The array will contain
>   the minimum number of bytes required to represent this BigInteger,
>   including at least one sign bit, which is (ceil((this.bitLength() +
>   1)/8)).

Sadly, this rules out what `Data.Binary` offers. Is there something efficient to do a `ByteString` <-> `Integer` conversion following this convention somewhere in the libraries? If not, how can it be done?

Based on the answer from Thomas M. DuBuisson (and the following discussion) I currently have

```
i2bs :: Integer -> B.ByteString
i2bs x
   | x == 0 = B.singleton 0
   | x < 0 = i2bs $ 2 ^ (8 * bytes) + x
   | otherwise = B.reverse $ B.unfoldr go x
   where
      bytes = (integerLogBase 2 (abs x) + 1) `quot` 8 + 1
      go i = if i == 0 then Nothing
                       else Just (fromIntegral i, i `shiftR` 8)

integerLogBase :: Integer -> Integer -> Int
integerLogBase b i =
     if i < b then
        0
     else
        -- Try squaring the base first to cut down the number of divisions.
        let l = 2 * integerLogBase (b*b) i
            doDiv :: Integer -> Int -> Int
            doDiv i l = if i < b then l else doDiv (i `div` b) (l+1)
        in  doDiv (i `div` (b^l)) l
```

Which is more verbose than what I was hoping for, still misses the `bs2i` function.

Comment: Does it have to be portable, or can you assume GHC with the `integer-gmp` package?

Comment: I'd prefer a portable solution. If I remember correctly, even GHC can be built without GMP? That would be a bit too fragile then.

Comment: Yes, it can be built with `integer-simple`. You could just be more efficient if you use the internals. One further question, do you want a `ByteString` containing only the bits of the number, or is it to be part of a larger `ByteString` so that you'd have a field specifying how many bytes make up the representation?

Comment: Only the raw bits are needed.

Answer (score 6):

Just steal the `i2bs` and `bs2i` routines from crypto-api and give them a slight modification:

```
import Data.ByteString as B

-- |@i2bs bitLen i@ converts @i@ to a 'ByteString'
i2bs :: Integer -> B.ByteString
i2bs = B.reverse . B.unfoldr (\i' -> if i' == 0 then Nothing
                                                else Just (fromIntegral i', i' `shiftR` 8))


-- |@bs2i bs@ converts the 'ByteString' @bs@ to an 'Integer' (inverse of 'i2bs')
bs2i :: B.ByteString -> Integer
bs2i = B.foldl' (\i b -> (i `shiftL` 8) + fromIntegral b) 0 . B.reverse
```

You can make this slightly more efficient by determining the bit size first and use the original `i2bs` to construct the bytestring in order (saving you the cost of reverse).

(EDIT: I should note this isn't tested with a Java parser, but this basic construct should be easy for you to mutate to take into account any missing bits).

Comment: This fails for negative numbers, `i2bs (-1)` does not return (it produces an infinite number of `0xff` bytes).

Comment: Arrgh, I was just (slowly) writing up something myself. Of course using this is more convenient. @Waldheinz Just compute the number of bytes you need (``bytes = (integerLogBase (abs n) + 1) `quot` 8 + 1``) and then write `2^(8*bytes) + n` for `n < 0`.

Comment: @DanielFischer well it seems this solution is insufficient so perhaps your code would be a welcome addition.

Comment: @Waldheinz True, this is basically for NATs and requires you to use abs and add your own sign bit.  Good observation.

Comment: Uh, it would be ugly, `Data.ByteString.Internal` and such. I don't think that's necessary. Just add a special case for 0 (I suppose that should give a one-byte `ByteString`) and the fix for negative `n`.

Comment: I don't think you want to reverse the `ByteString` when converting back to an integer. Just use `bs2i = B.foldl' (\i b -> (i `shiftL` 8) + fromIntegral b) 0`, since the most significant bit is the zeroth element according to the problem specification.

Comment: Everyone has suggestions to make this match the spec - please do steal this code and make a better answer!  Waldheinz can probably get the last of it from here, but having a complete answer is good too.

Comment: I updated the question with what I currently have based on the discussion here, but I'm still not there yet.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so a fully working solution based on the partial answer by Thomas M. DuBuisson is:

```
bs2i :: B.ByteString -> Integer
bs2i b
   | sign = go b - 2 ^ (B.length b * 8)
   | otherwise = go b
   where
      go = B.foldl' (\i b -> (i `shiftL` 8) + fromIntegral b) 0
      sign = B.index b 0 > 127

i2bs :: Integer -> B.ByteString
i2bs x
   | x == 0 = B.singleton 0
   | x < 0 = i2bs $ 2 ^ (8 * bytes) + x
   | otherwise = B.reverse $ B.unfoldr go x
   where
      bytes = (integerLogBase 2 (abs x) + 1) `quot` 8 + 1
      go i = if i == 0 then Nothing
                       else Just (fromIntegral i, i `shiftR` 8)

integerLogBase :: Integer -> Integer -> Int
integerLogBase b i =
     if i < b then
        0
     else
        -- Try squaring the base first to cut down the number of divisions.
        let l = 2 * integerLogBase (b*b) i
            doDiv :: Integer -> Int -> Int
            doDiv i l = if i < b then l else doDiv (i `div` b) (l+1)
        in  doDiv (i `div` (b^l)) l
```

I won't accept my own answer anytime soon in case someone wants to come up with something more neat to show of his skills. :-)

Comment: For GHC, `integerLogBase` is exported from `GHC.Float` (It's there because it's needed for the `fromRational` conversion to `Double` and `Float`). That's far more efficient than what you have for base 2, so you'd better use that. However, with 32-bit GHCs, that overflows for `|n| >= 2^(2^31)` (either version), which may fit in memory [with 64-bit GHCs, `Integer`s large enough for it to overflow won't fit in memory for a few more years].

Comment: @Niklas: I happily give credit to him, but for me it should be that the accepted answer to a question should do what the question asks for. This makes "using" SO easier: 1) Find similar question. 2) Copy+Paste accepted answer. 3) Profit. But Thomas' answer does not really match the question, that's why I posted my own for reference and discussion.

Comment: @Waldheinz: While I disagree that you should copy&paste answers to similar questions (you should mark the question as a duplicate instead!), I agree that having a fully working answer as the accepted one is useful for visitors.

Comment: @NiklasB. : I did not mean using copypasta to answer SO questions, but to get actual work done outside of SO. :-)

Comment: No need to accept a partial answer like mine, accept your own if it does what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without needing to calculate the size first. For negative numbers, it does the equivalent of inverting all the bits, performs the calculation, then inverts the bits again.

```
i2bs :: Integer -> B.ByteString
i2bs x = B.reverse . B.unfoldr (fmap go) . Just $ changeSign x
  where
    changeSign :: Num a => a -> a
    changeSign | x < 0     = subtract 1 . negate
               | otherwise = id
    go :: Integer -> (Word8, Maybe Integer)
    go x = ( b, i )
      where
        b = changeSign (fromInteger x)
        i | x >= 128  = Just (x `shiftR` 8 )
          | otherwise = Nothing

bs2i :: B.ByteString -> Integer
bs2i xs = changeSign (B.foldl' go 0 xs)
  where
    changeSign :: Num a => a -> a
    changeSign | B.index xs 0 >= 128 = subtract 1 . negate
               | otherwise           = id
    go :: Integer -> Word8 -> Integer
    go i b = (i `shiftL` 8) + fromIntegral (changeSign b)
```

Comment: `go` in `bs2i` is always called with `i=0`, and `(shiftL 0 8) = 0`, so I don't understand why `go` isn't just `go b = fromIntegral (changeSIgn b)`